# Put HTML into ValidationError in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to put an anchor tag into this ValidationError:

```
Customer.objects.get(email=value)
            if self.register:
                # this address is already registered
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    _('An account already exists for this email address')
                )
```

The anchor tag would be `<a href="some/url/to/login">Log in instead</a>`

So, the error message when a user inputs an email that already exists would be something like:

'An account already exists for this email address. `<a>`**Log in** instead`</a>`?'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it works? `raise forms.ValidationError(_(mark_safe('An account already exists for this email address. <a>Log in instead</a>')))`. Take a look at [mark_safe()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe)

Comment: @goliney I get this error: global name 'mark_safe' is not defined.

Comment: import it at the beginning of `.py` file: `from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe`

Comment: unfortunately, this method does not work if the ValidationError’s message contains parameters. this is because Django does `message %= error.params` (https://github.com/django/django/blob/0bf1330fe41e9a8ce04806c764fd5c90e1bafe5d/django/core/exceptions.py#L174), which removes the “safe” flag from the resulting string...

Answer (score 14):

This worked:

```
Customer.objects.get(email=value)
    if self.register:
    # this address is already registered
    raise forms.ValidationError(
    (_(mark_safe('An account already exists for this email address. <a href="#" class="email_error">Log in instead?</a>')))
 )
```

...but also needed this at the top of the Python file:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
```