# Line Breaks and rendering HTML in Django Rest Framework's ValidationError

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Working on a Django/DRF-React-Redux project. So I want to return specific messages for user login validation. If the credentials don't match, they get one error string, if the user is inactive they get another error string.

What I am trying to do is for one of the messages I need two line breaks and the other I want to render HTML because it should contain an email address. Anything I have read on SO, is not working. For example, regarding the HTML:

[Put HTML into ValidationError in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786845/put-html-into-validationerror-in-django)

Here is the method:

```
def validate(self, data):
    username = data['username']
    password = data['password']
    user_qs = User.objects.filter(username__iexact=username)
    # user_b = User.objects.filter(email__iexact=username)
    # user_qs = (user_a | user_b).distinct()
    if user_qs.exists() and user_qs.count() == 1:
        user_obj = user_qs.first()
        password_passes = user_obj.check_password(password)
        if not user_obj.is_active:
            raise ValidationError((mark_safe('This user is inactive. Please contact The Company at <a href="mailto:accounts@example.com?subject=Inactive Account">accounts@example.com</a>.')))
        if password_passes:
            data['username'] = user_obj.username
            payload = jwt_payload_handler(user_obj)
            token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
            data['token'] = token
            return data
    raise ValidationError('The credentials provided are invalid.\nPlease verify the username and password are correct.')
```

Needless to say it isn't rendering as expected on the front-end. Doesn't break the lines and doesn't render HTML, just just displays it as typed.

I guess if all else fails, I can simplify the server responses to "Invalid" or "Inactive" and just render the full message client-side.

Comment: Check if it returned as an array such that on the client side, you may need to do error[0]

Comment: What does DRF return exactly? Maybe the problem is not in django but in js

Comment: @dkarchmer Double checked and yeah I needed to add the array index. While it renders properly in the console with a few line breaks, it isn't rendering on the front-end. So seems like serg's suggestion is probably right too. React is doing something to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up coming across: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` which took care of the issue.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I changed the following for the DRF serializer.

```
def validate(self, data):
    username = data['username']
    password = data['password']
    user_qs = User.objects.filter(username__iexact=username)
    # user_b = User.objects.filter(email__iexact=username)
    # user_qs = (user_a | user_b).distinct()
    if user_qs.exists() and user_qs.count() == 1:
        user_obj = user_qs.first()
        password_passes = user_obj.check_password(password)
        if not user_obj.is_active:
            raise ValidationError(mark_safe('This user is inactive.<br><br>Please contact The Company at <a href="mailto:accounts@example.com?subject=Inactive Account">accounts@example.com</a>.'))
        if password_passes:
            data['username'] = user_obj.username
            payload = jwt_payload_handler(user_obj)
            token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
            data['token'] = token
            return data
    raise ValidationError(mark_safe('The credentials provided are invalid.<br><br>Please verify the username and password are correct.'))
```

Then on the React FE I had to change the `signin.js` container from:

```
renderAlert() {
    if (this.props.errorMessage) {
        return (
            <div className="alert alert-danger">
                {this.props.errorMessage}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

To:

```
renderAlert() {
    if (this.props.errorMessage) {
        return (
            <div className="alert alert-danger" 
                 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.errorMessage}}>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note, to use mark_safe : 
`from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe`